# how to get the old dark theme color which was grey in Vuetify v2

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Recently, I updated my `package.json` file and my `vuetify` updated to the newest and the dark theme is now very dark. it used to be more grey. I can't find anything to get back to this grey version of the dark theme in v2.

heres my code:

```
theme: {
    dark:true,
    themes: {
        dark: {
            primary: '#4caf50',
            secondary: '#4caf50',
            tertiary: '#495057',
            accent: '#82B1FF',
            error: '#f55a4e',
            info: '#00d3ee',
            success: '#5cb860',
            warning: '#ffa21a',
            general: '#2196F3',
            purple: '#BA55D3',
            dark: '#1c1c1c',
        },

    },
},
```

Comment: This is the reason why most developers use git (or other versioning systems). Did you think it was because we like to over-complicate things and feel special about it?

Comment: Good point, unfortunatelly i havent used it right now.

Comment: Rollback Vuetify in `package.json` and run `npm i` until you find the right version. Notice most IDE's will hint existing versions while you type: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGUWp.png Another idea is to go over Vuetify's changelog and see where they changed it. Maybe they provided a way to keep the legacy colors by using a setting or something.